create pivot table laravel blade and js
from a controller in Laravel I'm trying to create a pivot table that opens and closes as needed but I can't understand where the problem is. the masterzone opens and closes but subarea and microarea don't and I don't know why.. can anyone sleep where I'm doing wrong?
Controller
$audits = DB::table('esiti_audit')
    ->where('frequency_audit', "DAY")
    ->select(['master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea', 'data_audit', 'esito'])
    ->orderBy('master_zone', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('subarea', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('microarea', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('data_audit', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

$data = [];

foreach ($audits as $audit) {
    $data[$audit->master_zone][$audit->subarea][$audit->microarea][] = [
        'esito' => $audit->esito,
        'data_audit' => $audit->data_audit
    ];
}

Blade
@foreach ($data as $masterZone => $subareas)
  <h2 onclick="toggleSection('{{ $masterZone }}')">{{ $masterZone }}</h2>
  <div id="{{ $masterZone }}" style="display: none;">
    <table>
      @foreach ($subareas as $subarea => $microareas)
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" onclick="toggleSection('{{ $subarea }}')">
            <h3>{{ $subarea }}</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="{{ $subarea }}" style="display: none;">
          @foreach ($microareas as $microarea => $audits)
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" onclick="toggleSection('{{ $subarea . $microarea }}')">
                <h3>{{ $microarea }}</h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="{{ $subarea . $microarea }}" style="display: none;">
              @foreach ($audits as $audit)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ $audit['esito'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $audit['data_audit'] }}</td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </table>
  </div>
@endforeach

JS
<script>
function toggleSection(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (element.style.display === "none") {
        element.style.display = "table-row";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>


in this screen montaggio and spedizioni are the main masterzones and they work but the related subareas and microareas have already exploded I would like to be able to make them explode and implode at will like I do for the first ones but I can't thank you all very much

Solved, I'll post the code for anyone who needs it in the future
New code Blade work
@foreach ($data as $masterZone => $subareas)
    <h2>{{ $masterZone }}</h2>
    <ul class="master-zone" style="display: none;">
        @foreach ($subareas as $subarea => $microareas)
            <li class="subarea">
                {{ $subarea }}
                <span class="toggle">+</span>
            </li>
            <ul class="subarea-list" style="display: none;">
                @foreach ($microareas as $microarea => $audits)
                    <li class="microarea">
                        {{ $microarea }}
                        <span class="toggle">+</span>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="microarea-list" style="display: none;">
                        @foreach ($audits as $audit)
                            <li class="audit">Esito: {{ $audit['esito'] }}, Data Audit: {{ $audit['data_audit'] }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach

New Js
@foreach ($data as $masterZone => $subareas)
    <h2>{{ $masterZone }}</h2>
    <ul class="master-zone" style="display: none;">
        @foreach ($subareas as $subarea => $microareas)
            <li class="subarea">
                {{ $subarea }}
                <span class="toggle">+</span>
            </li>
            <ul class="subarea-list" style="display: none;">
                @foreach ($microareas as $microarea => $audits)
                    <li class="microarea">
                        {{ $microarea }}
                        <span class="toggle">+</span>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="microarea-list" style="display: none;">
                        @foreach ($audits as $audit)
                            <li class="audit">Esito: {{ $audit['esito'] }}, Data Audit: {{ $audit['data_audit'] }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.toggle').forEach(function(toggle) {
        toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var parent = this.parentElement;
            var nextElement = parent.nextElementSibling;
            if (nextElement.style.display === 'none' || nextElement.style.display === '') {
                nextElement.style.display = 'block';
                this.textContent = '-';
            } else {
                nextElement.style.display = 'none';
                this.textContent = '+';
            }
        });
    });
</script>

final results


Check your rendered HTML, you have unnecessary<tr>s before/after some @foreachs

Hi, I'm trying in every way but apparently I can't get it to work. my idea is to create a sort of pivot table where everything is compressed and I would like to explode and implode as I like but I can't understand where the problem is, I add the screen in a json file so maybe it's clearer that I would like to get the same as the json file but in the blade

Did you fix the faulty <tr>s?

yes I tried but nothing do you think I removed the wrong tr?

Since I can't see your edited code I really have no idea

posted the new one at the bottom of everything

Well, you removed every <tr>, which is invalid. Little refresher on tables. Keep those with an id. Better yet, use <div>s instead of a table. Good luck!

I posted your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work. thank you all the same

Solved it, I posted the new code and a screen shot for you to see

Grats, nice to hear!

thanks to you, I hope this helps people who have the same problem as me
